# Grails Custom Tag Library not working in Main Layout

Tags: grails, layout, taglib

I have made a custom Tag library which is used to import all the needed JS and CSS files which are needed on all GSP pages. Now the problem is that if I try to use the TagLib on Main.gsp layout then the tag library doesnot work. But if I do the same on normal pages then it works perfectly fine.

I have even used a `println` to check on the console if the Tag library is being computed but nothing is getting printed. On the contrary if I use the same tagLib on the page then this `println` prints on console which proves it works there.

Is there any way to make it work on Main.gsp layout?

The code for taglib is-

```
def globalCSS = { attrs, body ->
    out << '<!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->'
    out << '<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css', file: 'font-awesome.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons', file: 'simple-line-icons.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css', file: 'bootstrap.min.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+g.resource(dir: 'assets/global/plugins/uniform/css', file: 'uniform.default.css', absolute: true)+'"/>'
    out << '<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->'

    println("Hello css");
}
```

The code for main.gsp is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <myUI:globalCSS/>
        <g:layoutHead/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:layoutBody/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does "not work" mean?  errors, exceptions, ...?

Comment: It means there is no error, no exceptions. But the tagLib code is not executing. And to let you know when I use the same tagLib on any page other than Main layout it works, so tagLib otherwise works but not on Main.gsp.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're reinventing functionality that is already provided by the resources/asset-pipeline plugins. Unless you have a good reason not to, I would suggest you use one of those instead, preferably asset-pipeline.

Comment: Hi thankyou for the reply. I am actually making a plugin which I have to provide to other users and have to make it work using a custom taglib as these needs to be imported via just one tag. By the way, it was just an example otherwise too the taglibs don't seem to work or do anything if used in main.gsp layout.